# Change 'Build Action' property for all images in a project in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm wondering if there is a way to update a property for all images in my Visual Studio project?

I have multiple nested folders of images, and I'd like to change their 'Build Action' property from 'Resource' to 'Content'.

Currently I can only highlight and select/change all images in one folder. This is very time consuming when I have hundreds of folders and thousands of images.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Professional.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d8eff95a-1130-48c6-9612-0077d5c3055f/change-build-action-type-for-multiple-files?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: @Nair That looks like just the ticket, many thanks!

Comment: Cool. Post it answer. So other will be benefited.

Comment: Certainly will give it a go later and if it works I'll post an answer :-)

Comment: @Nair I followed that suggestion, needed some updating as the API has changed significantly. It couldn't resolve those environment variables often used such as '$(SolutionDir)' etc. Maybe there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more research, I found a way to edit the project file in the editor. Here are the steps I took to do this:

1. Right-click on project, select 'Unload Project'. The project name should now be displayed with 'unavailable' displayed next to it.
2. Right-click on project and choose 'Edit ProjectName.csproj' from the menu. The project XML will now be displayed in the editor.
3. Use the search and replace functionality (Ctrl+H) to update 'Resource' to 'Content' for all desired images.
4. Right-click on the project and select 'Reload Project'

This was pretty quick and didn't require creating an additional project to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 6):

You can leverage wildcard in project file.

1. Remove all images from your project. If they are in under the same root folder, it would be easy.
2. Open your .csproj in notepad or VS (tip: Productivity Power Tool makes it extremely easy).
3. Add a item group

   ```
   <ItemGroup>
       <Content Include="images/**/*.png">
           <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
       </Content>
   </ItemGroup>
   ```

   Note `**` is used to include folders recursively. It will include all png files under project file with BuildAction = Content.

Comment: Thanks for posting that @qxg I guess I should mention that I'll also need to update 'Copy to Output Directory' to 'Copy if newer' for each image as well. Is there a way to do that also?

Comment: @SimonBosley, see my updated answer. You can always make this change in UI and check generated csproj file.

Comment: Just to confirm @qxg, this would mean that the files aren't available in the Visual Studio project after they've been removed?

Comment: @SimonBosley, these files will be added back as long as their path matches `Include` path. However, be careful next time you add a new image. Don't add new image in VS anymore. Just copy them to project folder, and they will added to project automatically. Of course, reloading project is required.

Comment: what happens if you add an image manually as well as it being included automatically? I'm part of a large software team, so I can't guarantee everyone will follow this method.

Comment: project file will go back to original content with every image file explicitly added as project item. You lose the ability to configure them centrally. If your resource to content modification is one time job, it's not a problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109916/discussion-between-simon-bosley-and-qxg).