# Changing/Updating Image in XAML

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

I'm having an issue updating my Images in my Xamarin UWP app. First, I'd like to say I have seen multiple other threads on this issue, but none have been able to solve my predicament and a lot are *very* outdated.

Here is my scenario: I have three images I am using, named green.png, red.png, and gray.png. I am displaying one Image in my Xamarin app, and depending on a specific float called in my associated .cs file, I want to change the Image to another color. So, for example, if the float goes below 15, I want the Image to be the Red one.

Here is how I am currently displaying my Images *without code for changing them*, i.e. this code works fine and my Images appear in the app:

```
<Image Source="{pages:ImageResource BLE.Client.Pages.red.png}" Opacity="0.6"/>
```

They are currently stored in the same directory as the XAML files themselves. I know that on Android there is a *Resources* folder, but I don't see any equivalent for UWP, so I am loading my Images this way.

One way I attempted to do this based on another post I saw here is this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding HeadColor, StringFormat='pages:ImageResource BLE.Client.Pages.\{0\}.png', Mode=TwoWay}" Opacity="0.6"/>
```

The way this is supposed to function is depending on the value of my float, I used the string HeadColor in my .cs file and do an OnPropertyChanged on it. It always contains either the string "green", "red", or "gray", and with this method it should slot itself into the Image location string. However, this **does not work.**

For reference, here is how I update my HeadColor string in my .cs file:

```
private string _HeadColor;
public string HeadColor {get => _HeadColor; set {_HeadColor = value; OnPropertyChanged("HeadColor");}}
...
if (SensorAvgValue > 15) {_HeadColor = "green";}
else                     {_HeadColor = "red";}
RaisePropertyChanged(() => HeadColor);
```

I have also tried using an IValueConverter, but that does not work either.

So, in summary, my question is how to best go about dynamically changing which Image I'd like to use. They are all the same dimensions and in the same directory, the only difference being their names "green.png", "red.png", and "gray.png". Is there a better way to call/load the Images?

Thanks!

Comment: first, does your VM implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?  If it does not then none of this will work.  Second, this `{_HeadColor = "Green";}` is setting the **private** variable, not the **public property** which triggers the `PropertyChanged` event.  Third, when you say the final method "does not work" does it not set any color at all, or does it work for just the initial color but not for subsequent changes?

Comment: Hi @Jason. The final method does not work for any color, so it could be an issue with my implementation there. Regarding the Private/Public variables, the reason I did it this way is because I have the exact same setup for another variable which updates a Label in my app. Same code with different variable names, just I am displaying the String as a Label rather than using it as an Image address. It updates/dynamically changes perfectly, no issue there. it's just when the string is used to define where my image is drawn from that it seems to not function right.

Comment: **1)** Trevor - your hardcoded one that works uses `"red"` in name. Your HeadColor is `"Red"`. Change color strings to lowercase? **2)** @Jason - `RaisePropertyChanged` forces the PropertyChanged event (maybe 
 mvvmcross), so that part should be okay.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve apologies Steve, the uppercase/lowercase is my own error when writing this post, all the cases are the same in my actual code, so that is not my current issue. I've updated the cases on the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for me on iOS - I don't have a UWP env to test with, but it should work the same.  I have two images "reddot.png" and "greendot.png" in my iOS Resources

```
<StackLayout Padding="20,50,20,50">
    <Image Source="{Binding HeadColor, StringFormat='\{0\}dot.png'}" Opacity="0.6"/>
    <Button Clicked="ChangeColor" Text="Click!!" />
</StackLayout>
```

code-behind

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string headColor = "red";

    public string HeadColor
    {
        get
        { 
          return headColor; 
        }
        set 
        {
            headColor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext = this;
    }

    protected void ChangeColor(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (HeadColor == "red")
        {
            HeadColor = "green";
        }
        else
        {
            HeadColor = "red";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This did end up working, but I also utilized the code on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788578/change-build-action-property-for-all-images-in-a-project-in-visual-studio. In this one, I used the changing build actions for the images and putting them in the UWP Assets folder, so the same code you had but with the 'Assets/' directory path added before the .png filename.